# Formatting the data coming from webservice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, formatting

I am using asp.net and vb.net (code behind) to fetch some data from a web service.

While fetching the data I am unable to format it.

I tried this:

```
 label_date.test = trim(arData(25))
```

Which gives the output as : `01012012`

I would like the output as : `01/01/2012`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dateString As String = trim(arData(25))
Dim dateValue As String

If DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MMddyyyy", Nothing, _
     DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then
     label_date.test = dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
End If
```

Comment: Now I am getting the error : 'The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GeorgianCalendar.

Comment: What is the string? Is it always "01012012"?

Comment: the data coming from my be null or a date in month date year (MM/dd/yyyy) format. if date is null nothing to display, if date is fetched it should display date.

Comment: also one more field : label_amount.Text = trim(arData(11)   it is coming 0020000  but it should come 200.00  or $200.00

Comment: If date is not there, from the webservice it is coming 00000000       so i want to validate this one. if it is 00000000 nothing to print. else date should print.

Comment: Edited my answer again. As for the amount, just use int.Parse and split it by 100.